# DAX: Avoid summing up repeated numbers

Tags: powerpivot, dax, excel-2016

I have a table that includes columns for accountID, revenue, quarter and estimated revenue. the issue with this table is that the revenue repeats for each quarter. 
The table is perfect if I'm trying to find the estimate, but as soon as I sum the revenue, it basically quadruples for each account. 
I can divide by 4, but that gives a wrong revenue number for each quarter. 
Is there a DAX function that allows me to show "4000" for each quarter, but at account/company level, it would not quadruple in size?

AccountID | Revenue |   Quarter |   Estimate 
123       | 4000    |Q1         |   4000
123       | 4000    |Q2         |   5000
123       | 4000    |Q3         |   2000
123       | 4000    |Q4         |   4000
456       | 3000    |Q1         |   4000
456       | 3000    |Q2         |   5000
456       | 3000    |Q3         |   1000
456       | 3000    |Q4         |   3000

What I would like to see in pivot

Account ID | Quarter | Sum of Revenue | Sum of Estimate
123       | Q1    |4000         |   4000
123       | Q2    |4000         |   5000
123       | Q3    |4000         |   2000
123       | Q4    |4000         |   4000
123 Total         |4000         |   15000
456       | Q1    |3000         |   4000
456       | Q2    |3000         |   5000
456       | Q3    |3000         |   1000
456       | Q4    |3000         |   3000
456 Total         |3000         |   13000
Grand Total       |7000             |   2800

Comment: What visualization are you using? If you don't want the column be summarized set the `Don't Summarize` option.

Comment: I'm using just the regular pivot table on top powerpivot. I want it to Summarize, just not quadruple the amount. So if I have AccountID, Quarter, Revenue, Estimate. I'm ok with Revenue to be repeated for each quarter, but when I have multiple accounts, I want the sum to be simply revenue of those two accounts, not sum of revenue 4 quarters x 2 accounts.

Comment: Do you have accountID in rows and Revenue in values? Note pivot tables group the repeated values in rows.

Comment: I understand that's the default, I'm asking whether I could have DAX formula that allows me to not group repeated value. Edited OP to show what I need

Answer (score 0):

Create two measures `EstimateMeasure` and `RevenueMeasure`:

```
EstimateMeasure = SUM(Table1[Estimate])
```

`RevenueMeasure = SUMX(VALUES(Table3[Revenue]),Table3[Revenue])`

Add previously created measures to `Values` and `AccountID` & `Quarter` in your pivot table.

It should produce the following output in Power BI.

[image]

Note I don't have access to PowerPivot in this moment, so I can't post the complete table with subtotals. But you can add subtotals in PowerPivot to get the total per `AccountID`.

Let me know if this helps.